# Javascript function not getting called in Drupal 7 which used to run proper in Drupal 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

I am in the process of migrating my Drupal 6 site to Drupal 7. As a result i am facing some issues with the code.
The calling of javascript laced with jquery etc is different in Drupal 7 is what i have read.
[This is the image of the page i had in Drupal 6.](http://imageshack.us/f/577/dashboarjs.jpg/)
On change of the dropdown box, the table above it gets populated with projects belonging to that 
status. This works fine in Drupal 6.
But in Drupal 7 i see [this javascript error.](http://imageshack.us/f/848/d7dashboard.jpg/)

This is the form element for the Dropdown in my php file.

```
<? php
 $form['status_list'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('Freeway Project Statuses'),
'#options' => array(
  0 => t('-Select Status-'),
  1 => t('Draft'),
  2 => t('NotSpecified'),
  3 => t('Quote'),
  4 => t('Forecasted'),
  5 => t('InEvaluation'),
  6 => t('Cancelled'),
  7 => t('Booked'),
  8 => t('InProduction'),
  9 => t('Completed'),
  10 => t('Closed'),
 ),
 '#default_value' => array('0' => 'Select Status'),
 '#weight' => 0,
);
```

And this is the JavaScript
I have modified it with the additional tags for Drupal 7

```
 (function$){ .. })(jQuery); .
```

These tags were not needed in Drupal 6.

```
      (function$){
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#edit-status-list").change(function() {
     var selectedStatus = $(this).find(":selected").text();
     var charExists = ((window.location.href).indexOf('?') >= 0) ? true : false;

    if(charExists){
    var split = (window.location.href).split('?');
    var loc = split[0];

      loc = loc+"?status="+selectedStatus;  
    self.location.href= loc;

    }

    else{
     var locf = window.location.href+"?status="+selectedStatus;   
     self.location.href= locf;

     }

     });

     $("#create-freeway-project").submit(function() {
      $(":submit", this).attr("disabled", "disabled");

     });

    $(".common_link_class").click(function() {
          //alert("Hello");

       var count = ($(this).data("clicks") || 0) + 1;
       $(this).data("clicks", count);


        if ($(this).data("clicks") >= 1) {

       }


       if ($(this).data("clicks") >= 2) {

         return false;
       }
     });


      $("#edit-analysis-code-one").change(function () {
        // Get the configs and split them.
        var cfgs = _get_configs("edit-custRef");
        var split_cfgs = cfgs.split('/');

        // Create some new configs and put it back into the configs  textfield.
        //var new_cfgs = $(this).val() +"/"+ cfgs[1];
        var new_cfgs = $("#edit-analysis-code-one option:selected").text() +"/"+ cfgs[1];

        $("#edit-custRef").val(new_cfgs);
      });

      $("#edit-analysis-code-two").change(function () {
        // Get the configs and split them.
        var cfgs = _get_configs("edit-custRef");
        var split_cfgs = cfgs.split('/');

        // Create some new configs and put it back into the configs textfield.
        //var new_cfgs = cfgs[0] +"/"+ $(this).val();
        var new_cfgs = cfgs[0] +"/"+ $("#edit-analysis-code-two option:selected").text()
        $("#edit-custRef").val(new_cfgs);
     });


   });

 })(jQuery); 


(function$){
function _get_configs(id) {

  return $("#"+ id).val();

}   
})(jQuery);
```

`#edit_status_list` is the dropdown of our interest.

Would like to have your suggestions as to what additional change needs to be done for proper javascipt calling in Drupal 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
(function($) {
```

Not

```
(function$ {
```

What you've got is a syntax error. The first one instantiates a function such that its first argument will be available via the symbol `$` in its body code.  The function is invoked after the body:

```
  // ...
})(jQuery);
```

and the global "jQuery" object is passed in as the argument.  This setup assures your code access to the correct framework (that is, to jQuery) via the common "$" symbol without having to worry about another external binding for "$".

Comment: Thanks Pointy the error for javascript throwing error was resolved thanks to this. But the Jquery method is not reflecting. I will raise a new question for the same.

Comment: Hi Pointy i would like to have your views on this associated question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264892/drupal-7-table-theme-unable-to-display-values-seen-in-firebug