# Drupal 7 table theme unable to display values seen in Firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

I am migrating from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 and had a Java script related issue which got [resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264014/javascript-function-not-getting-called-in-drupal-7-which-used-to-run-proper-in-d) .
Now i am able to see the pages without the error i used to see earlier. The [screen](http://imageshack.us/f/40/invisiblerj.jpg/) shows the firebug view of the page post the dropdown change and javascript run. The Firebug shows the value of the project ID it acquired but the table shows blank.
[This](http://pastebin.com/CEmnCdiz) is the method in php and this is the [table theme](http://pastebin.com/dGh4teXr) used for displaying the table seen in the screenshot.
All this was visible in Drupal 6 but i am unsure as to what additional changes need to be done for Drupal 7. This is the [Javascript file](http://pastebin.com/UvVPpK2g) used in the entire page for the functionality.
Would like to have your views as to what is missing in the Drupal 7 version of my customization.

Thanks
A

Comment: Well I'm not a Drupal user/programmer/customizer so I'm afraid I'm not much help. I don't even know PHP :-) Maybe some Drupal API changed?